# How to make banner image stretch across the page on large screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage I'm working on and I've never had this much difficulty with an image before. I'm using media queries, and I started out with the small screen and am working my way up to large. The small and medium are fine, but the large image only covers the left side of the page and leaves the other half blank. I have it between the header and the nav, so it really sticks out. I can't figure out why it's not using the largest image I have. it's over 6000px, so it should reach the edge fine. I will scale it down after I get the thing to reach across the page. I will post the media queries and CSS below, and the HTML for the images.

```css
/*small view*/

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 539px;
  background-color: #fee9c1;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 499px;
}

header {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

media query :
/*medium view*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
  .banner img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  body {
    max-width: 1150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  main {
    max-width: 1150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}


/*large view*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 770px) {
  main {
    max-width: 1150px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .banner picture img {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x250.jpg" media="(min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 539px)">
    <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/800x400.jpg" media="(min-width: 540px) and (max-width: 799px)">
    <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x600.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1440px">
    <img src="images/welcomesign.jpg" alt="alt txt">
  </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: because body max-width is set to 1150px. so no content can be wider then 1150px.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
  .banner img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  body {
    max-width: 1150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  ...
}
```

This line is causing the issue. Every screen with a width of 540px or above has set the bdoy max width set to 1150px. Sicne your media queries for large screens dont overwrite thise property and value it still applies. Means the body has a max-width of 1150px and no content can be wider then that.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any CSS telling the image to stretch the full width, so I believe you need something like:

```
.banner img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it is right in the css within the media queires. Besides that is not causing the issue.

Comment: I see `max-width` but I don't see `width`. Max width will prevent the image from exceeding the container width, but it will not stretch the image to fill the container if the native image width is smaller than the container's width.

Comment: the image has a width of 6000px as descriped. So it will msot certainly fill out the width. But the issue is: `body { max-width: 1150px; }` which also limtis the image to 1150px;